# Linear Algebra - linear dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \{v_1,v_2,....,v_n\}$ $A$ vector group in linear space $V$.

If $v_1 \not\in Sp\{v_2,....,v_n\}$ and $v_1+v_n \in Sp\{v_1,...v_{n-1}\}$

Prove that $\{v_2,..,v_n\}$ linear dependant.

**My solution (Not full)**

Not full solution :
$$v_1+v_n=\alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}$$
$$v_1=\alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}-v_n$$ 
$$v_1-\alpha_1v_1=\alpha_2v_2+...+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}-v_n$$
$$v_1(1-\alpha_1)=\alpha_2v_2+...+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}-v_n$$

since $-v_n \neq Sp(-v_n)$ even if $\alpha_1 \neq 1$ I could not conclude anything using $(*)$, If $\alpha_1=1$ I can't conclude that :

$$\alpha_2v_2+...+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}-v_n=0$$

Is non-trival solution.

Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: @Timbuc Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Notice that if $1-\alpha_1 \neq 0$ then it implies (from your equations) that $v_1 \in span\{v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$. So, $\alpha_1=1$. This implies from the first equation that $v_n \in span\{v_2,\cdots,v_{n-1}\}$

Comment: I understood the case when $1-\alpha_1 \neq 0$, but I don't understand case of $\alpha_1=1$, in this case $Sp\{\alpha_2v_2+...+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}\}-v_n=0$ this is not equal to $Sp\{\alpha_2v_2+...+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}+\alpha_nv_n\}=0$

Comment: @JaVaPG: I confess that I do not understand your comment. Please take a while to think about what I wrote. If $\alpha_1=1$ then from the first equation $v_1+v_n=v_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_{-1}v_{n-1}$. Cancel out $v_1$. Then by definition of span, $v_n$ is in span of $v_2,\cdots,v_{n-1}$, which by definition is equivalent to saying $v_2,\cdots v_n$ are linearly dependent.